# Run an SSIS solution with a different account

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I have two windows accounts, one is the default regular account (account 1) and the other account (account 2).

in many cases, i need to launch visual studio using the other account (to do this, click run with a different user) with no problem. My problem is, now i have a ssis solution saved in the file system, i'd like to open it with my account #2.

If i clicked to open the solution, it will be opened with account #1 automatically. I tried to first open visual studio with account#2, then wanted to loaded the solution file from there, but I can't find this solution file anywhere.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going forward you'll want to save all your code in a central location that isn't the default (Something like C:\users...). Instead, you're want to have a folder say something like C:\MyCode...

Create that central folder, copy the solution and folder contents there, then your second account will be able to access that central location just like the first account.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how RunAs another user works from Windows Explorer extension but it likely has the solution in the "other you" Users folders.

Assuming you have a setup like domain\kay and domain\a-kay (former is your normal account, second is the admin version of "you")

Your normal account probably uses a path like

```
C:\Users\kay\source\repos
```

or

```
C:\Users\kay\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects
```

The admin version of yourself is going to use a pathing like

```
C:\Users\a-kay\source\repos
```

or

```
C:\Users\a-kay\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects
```

The only way to know is to hop onto the alternate account and open up the solution in Visual Studio. Right click on the Solution itself and pick "Open Folder in file explorer"

[image]

or go to Properties and then examine the Path

[image]

Copy that path and then open VS as yourself and if you have permissions to navigate to the path, you can open the solution.

Otherwise, you will need to switch to the Other account and move the solution to a shared space. For this reason, I home all my code from C:\src that way my normal and my admin self can access the code.